# What’s another method for displaying multiple choice results?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, project

I’m fairly new to web programming and for our first project, I am building a ten question quiz using the DOM. I’m using radio buttons as well. With that in mind, what are some ways to show quiz results other than prompt, alert, and console? I’ve been Googling and researching like a mad man, but the only results I find require the alert or prompt functions! Can someone point me in the right direction so I can get this project done without losing my sanity?

Comment: `document.querySelector("#result").textContent = "Right :)"`

Comment: I’m so sorry, can you elaborate on this suggestion?

Comment: The idea is that you modify the DOM document, using the [DOM API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction)

Comment: I didn’t think of that before. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

what are you mean "what are some ways to show quiz results other than prompt" ,
its web developing , its mean you are free , you can do all things that you want to do ,
**some suggestion :** 
if your problem is Appearance with prompet , you can use 3rd party libraries for this like [swal](https://sweetalert.js.org/docs/) , its beutiful , and other way you can build everything from base your self , you can make your radiobox and your alert with all things that you have in your mind , and if you point what you want , i can help you more.

Comment: The project I am working on is for a college class. The professor is prohibiting the use of prompt/console/alert codes.